# Porque simplexml_load_file retorna somente o primeiro resultado?

Tags: php

Olá estou tentando exibir os resultados de um arquivo XML mas ele me retorna apenas
os primeiros registros, a partir do segundo registro não tenho mais resultados.
o que pode ter de errado?

Por estar dentro de um `foreach` deveria mostrar todos os registros, mas somente os primeiros aparecem.

Tentei transformar o arquivo como um *string* mas o resultado foi o mesmo,
`simplexml_load_string($texto)` somente os primeiros registros foram exibidos.

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file("arquivo.xml");
 foreach ($xml->PEDIDOS as $PEDIDOS ) {
    echo $PEDIDOS->PEDIDO->PRODUTOS->PRODUTO->PRODUTO_COD."<br /><br />";
    echo $PEDIDOS->PEDIDO->PRODUTOS->PRODUTO->PRODUTO_COD_FORNECEDOR."<br /><br />";
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Problema resolvido... eu tinha que acessar por hierarquia para dar certo.

O correto é ($xml->PEDIDOS->PEDIDO as $PEDIDO):

```
$xml = simplexml_load_file("arquivo.xml");
 foreach ($xml->PEDIDOS->PEDIDO as $PEDIDO) {
    echo $PEDIDOS->PEDIDO->PRODUTOS->PRODUTO->PRODUTO_COD."<br /><br />";
    echo $PEDIDOS->PEDIDO->PRODUTOS->PRODUTO->PRODUTO_COD_FORNECEDOR."<br /><br />";
 }
```